# TaxCalculator function Javascript code is not working

Tags: javascript, calculator

```
const taxCalculator (price, state) => {
    let state = 'NY' || 'NJ';
     if (state === 'NY'){
        return price * 1.04;
    } else {
        return price * 1.06625;
    }
}
```

// I'm asked to define a function called taxCalculator that accepts the price of an item and a state. The taxCalculator should produce the after tax amount. If NY - 4% sales tax and NJ is 6.625% sales tax.

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Arrow Function Syntax:

**Missing the first `=`**

```
|var, const, let| identifier = (@param1, ...@paramN) => {...
  ...
  return result;
}

const taxCalculator = (price, state) => {...
```

**`state` already declared as the second parameter** -- remove `let` to make it valid -- remove the whole expression because it's useless:

```
let state = 'NY' || 'NJ';
```

The `if/else` statement already sorts out if `state` is `'NY'` or not. The expression above doesn't even really define, modify, etc. `state` at all.

---

#### Demo

**Note:** Details commented in demo

```js
/*
= Two ternaries:
- if state is 'NY' [?] then tax is 1.04
  [:] if state is 'NJ' [?] then tax is 1.06625
  [:] otherwise tax is nothing
- if tax is nothing [?] then return a message
  [:] otherwise return the product of price and tax as a
      String prefixed by '$' and truncated to 2 decicimals.
*/
const taxCalculator = (price, state) => {
  let tax = state === 'NY' ? 1.04 : state === 'NJ' ? 1.06625 : null;
  return tax === null ? `${state} not recognized` : '$' + (price * tax).toFixed(2);
}

console.log(taxCalculator(5.29, 'NJ'));
console.log(taxCalculator(5.29, 'CA'));
console.log(taxCalculator(5.29, 'NY'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed your code, try this:

```
const taxCalculator = (price, state) => {
if (state === 'NY' ) {
    return price * 1.04;
  } else {
    return price * 1.06625;
  }
}
```

console.log(taxCalculator(100, 'NY'));

Comment: when returning, you don't need `else`

Answer (score -1):

That's wrong your "state" variable is a param from your function. Please try:

```
function taxtaxCalculator(price, state) {
  let resp
  switch (state) {
     case 'NY':
         resp = price * 1.04
         break;

     case 'NJ':
         resp = price * 1.06625
         break;

     default:
         //Another case not defined in the question.
         resp = price * 1
         break;
  }
  return resp
```

}

Also if you want to support other cases than NY and NJ you can use a switch function inside in order to compare the "state" variable value.

Comment: the function naming is incorrect, fat arrow function should be like this:                         const taxCalculator = () => { ... }

Comment: This code is quite hard to read. It would also be hard to support other cases with this code.